# Building a custom Azure Logic App Connector for php based REST API's

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

### The Problem

I'm trying to build an a custom logic app connector for a php-based REST API. It works fine so far, i've got a working swagger.json - but I fail to submit (update connector) the logic app connector.

Its about the API for [Testrail](http://docs.gurock.com/testrail-api2/start).
The Problem seems to be in the Base-URL:

http://demo.testrail-fake.net/**index.php/?api/v2**

and it fails, because of the 'index.php?' construct.

### What i've tried

- I can't set it as the Host-Name, neither as Base Url.
  [image: Url Definition]
- I tried different things, mocking the url into the swagger.json (for each endpoint), this would work, but azure can't handle it anyhow.
  [image: Action Definition]

It's very frustrating, because

- i've built 2/5 Custom Connectors already, and this one has over 60
  Actions, which took a lot of time to build.
- no azure support, if you
  don't have twitter and not the right subscription

Comment: if issue is because of index.php then i would suggest to write a rewrite rule (which may redirect /index to /index.php) in your web server then then try.

Comment: thank you Vipul, thought about that too.. hosting an azure web app with a rewritemodule for a thirdparty api. But i'm trying to find a way around that, which should not cause more costs.

Answer (score 0):

With best practices and standards in mind, you really shouldn't have to be explicitly calling this PHP page in order to consume data from your API. Please re-configure your webserver to specify the default page to be `index.php`. That way, you may actually be avoiding a lot of other potential issues, especially, if you're designing a `RESTful service`.

Not sure what kind of server software you're running but making this change is pretty straight forward and typically entails modifying few or less options in the config file of your server. If you're under a unique circumstance that prevents you from making this change easily (in the context of `Azure App Services`), please open a separate post about that issue either here or on [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview). We'd be happy to assist you!

Comment: Hi, well it is a thirdparty api, which is hosted on azure, and not reachable to me. I received support from the azure logic app team and would tell the solution here. Maybe its a better way, like you said, to contact the owner of the azure web app for an rewriterule or something.

Comment: Oh.. in that case, have you looked into Azure APIM?

Comment: No... because it is not my api. I have nothing to do with it, except i want to create a custom logic app connector for it, to automate some processes.